# Why is Embedded array null instead of empty [ ] - Mongoose, MongoDb, Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue embedded array in mongodb, mongoose.
I have a schema (`cuisineSchema`) and inside this schema, I have an array (embedded array) of references (id's) to another schema (`mealCategorySchema`). The problem I am having is that when I try to update the embedded array, The embedded array is '`null`' instead of '`[ ]`' -empty, therefore the push method cannot be called to push new item, I get the error :

"`Cannot Read Property push of null`"

Code below :

```
//MONGOOSE MONDELS
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var cuisineSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  mealCategories:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'MealCategory'}]
})

var mealCategorySchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  description:String,
  imageUrl:String
});
```

//SAVING to mealCategories Array results in error "`cannot read property of null`"

```
Repo.Repository.prototype.addCategory=function(id,callback){

 this.Model.findById(id,function(err,doc){
    if(err){
        var error={error:500,message:err}
         callback(error);
    }

    //The error is thrown here at the push method
    //ERROR: CANNOT READ property push of null
    doc.mealCategories.push(id)

}
```

Why is the array `null` instead of `[ ]`, is there something wrong with my mongoose models declaration?

Comment: Have you `console.log` doc to see what it is actually returning? If so, can you show us the response?

Comment: Hi, the error is not coming from the database, the error is coming from the call to doc.mealCategories.push(id), the error says "Cannot read property push of null" because mealCategories array which is embedded in cuisineScema above is null instead of empty array []

Comment: This is the returned document   :
DOCUMEMNT { _id: 55b0ce6087231d4c39bfd42c,
  name: 'Spanish,
  __v: 0,
  mealCategories: null }

Comment: How are you setting the `mongoose.model`? is it like this: `mongoose.model('MealCategory', mealCategorySchema);` ?

Comment: It is now solved, but I find it kind of strange though, I change the name of the embedded document from mealCategories to mealCategory and it works! also i noticed other embedded document arrays were i used the plural ending 'ies' also had same issue, when i changed the names they all work

Comment: snozza 'exactly!', yes that is how I am setting the mongoose model, perhaps the name of the embedded array should be same as the mongoose.model name

Comment: Yes, it needs to be identical (including case)

Comment: Thanks very much! done solved!